# how to use ng-options for creating dropdowns

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

**JSON from REST**

```
http://localhost:8080/TestServer/webresources/com.rako.rma.product
{
brandBrandId: {
brandId: 2,
brandName: "Ticca",
isGun: true
},
created: "2015-04-09T12:06:37",
lotn: "1111",
productId: 1
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select data-ng-model="products.brandBrandId"
    data-ng-options="brand.brandName for brand in brandBrandId">
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.productService = productService;
                $scope.products = productService.query();
                console.log('$scope.products---->' + $scope.products.length)//Always 0!!!!

                $scope.$watch('products.length', function (length) {
                    if (length) { // <= first time length is changed from undefined to 0
                        console.log('(watch) ' + $scope.products.length); // <= will log correct length aka 1
                    }
                });
```

**Question**

1) How should I use that in html?
2) If and when I want to show both id and name, how?

Comment: `data-ng-options="p.brandBrandId.brandId as (p.brandBrandId.brandName + '('+p.brandBrandId.brandId+')') for p in products"`